# Get Share Button and FB Comments to work at the same time

Tags: javascript, facebook

I can't make both the share button and FB comments work at the same time.

If I put both scripts I don't get the comments. If I erase the first one I don't get the share button and if I erase the FB connect script I don't get the comments. What can I do?

This is my code:

```
<a expr:share_url='data:post.url' name='fb_share' style='position:absolute;'/> 

<script src='http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share' type='text/javascript'>
</script>


<script src='http://connect.facebook.net/es_ES/all.js#appId=183087358391609&amp;amp;xfbml=1'/>

<fb:comments numposts='5' publish_feed='true' width='624' xid='183087358391609'/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the order of your scripts. This has been faced and known before - [Facebook errors when using multiple .js api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463861/facebook-errors-when-using-multiple-js-api)