# Facebook errors when using multiple .js api

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have two Facebook API on my webpage, one is https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js and the other one is http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share

Now if I have both of these, then there is error: FB.init is not a function

Without the FB.Share API, everything is fine.

EDIT: .js file order caused the error. Now there is "e.root is undefined" error.

EDIT2:  fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never found anything missing from `all.js`, so that should suffice. What are you looking for in the second library?

There must be conflicting items across the two scripts that is causing a failure when ran in tandem.

Comment: Share button. This is the one I use - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/

Comment: Ok. A [similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765071/get-share-button-and-fb-comments-to-work-at-the-same-time) that never got answered :(

Comment: Perhaps [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309131/facebook-like-button-sometimes-appears-sometimes-not) should help. See the last answer there (replicating all.js locally, though may not be the best solution).

Comment: wow, the first solution actually did it, changed the orders of the .js files. Thanks buddy. :) Altough I get e.root is not defined error now.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete that second, first one covers everything

Comment: @nuclear: why do you think so? Why do you think it's "all.js" ?

Comment: if I delete one of the .js files, one of the Facebook scripts stop working.

Comment: Show me example where https://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/ and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/ works together.